# Is the DigitalWriteFast library still needed?

Tags: arduino-uno, digitalwrite

Yesterday I played with a SRAM 621024 SRAM 1 Mbit IC and since I use a lot of pins, digitalReads and digitalWrites are needed including shift registers (see [Example](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/36853/what-shift-register-would-i-need-for-input-or-output/36854#36854)

Since it took a long time for reading/writing one byte, I checked for faster ways and found some posts, one of them was using digitalWriteFast:
[Library](https://code.google.com/archive/p/digitalwritefast/)

However, it did not make any difference... is it possible that the (fast) digitalWrite is already implemented in the default Arduino IDE/library?

Update: I found out I made a stupid mistake and the library was not used.

Now I get different values:

- Writing 397.880 us per byte
- Reading 386.524 us per byte

Without the fast library:

- Writing 502.152 us per byte
- Reading 483.752 us per byte

Note, there is also a digitalReadFast, but this does not affect the speed.

I did some more testing and found out that a digitalReadFast/digitalWriteFast cost just about 8-12 us, a pinModeFast is 0 us (negligable), however a shiftOut for setting the address cost 120-124 us ... since 3 shifts are needed to set an address, this results in 360-372 us. Subtracting this from the measured times above, writing takes around 25-38 us and reading 15-27us. I possibly can maybe optimize the bit operations a little bit.

However, the end result for using this RAM chip with enough speed is to either change the shift register to a faster one or remove the shift registers at all. This would mean about 30 pins needed for the SRAM only. The conclusion is: better use a 3K256, 23LC1024 or similar variant.

(Note: I tried a ShiftOutFast file), which reduces a shiftout to 36 us but 3 times 36 is still over 100 us, too much to compare to a 3K256/23LC1024 solution.

Comment: If it made no difference then the chances are the bottleneck isn't the digital pin manipulation.

Comment: I didn't get a microsecond difference.

Comment: The time taken to use `digitalWrite()` pales into insignificance compared to the time taken to use shift registers.

Comment: Yes it seems so ... I already thought that shift registers would not be beneficially for a SRAM solution ... maybe when I have the Arduino Mega I will check direct pins (like 32 pins maximum). Than I don't need shift registers. If I ever will solder that solution, I doubt :-)

Comment: [The current `digitalWrite()`](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c#L138) still does quite a lot of stuff.

Comment: That's why I was surprised I did not see any difference.

Comment: Last time `digitalWrite()` changed [was six years ago](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blame/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c#L138)

Comment: I should point out that `micros()` has a 4 µs resolution, so a difference of less than 4 µs would not be measurable (if that is how you are measuring it).

Comment: @NickGammon Thanks for the info (although it does not make the conclusion much different)

Comment: *a pinModeFast is 0 us (negligable)* - it may in fact be 3 µs is my point. Unless you did a loop of 1000 of them, written in such a way that the compiler didn't optimize the loop away.

Comment: No not in this case, so negligible means 3 us (or less). Negligible is relative :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried to time `digitalWrite()` against direct port access with
the following code:

```c++
void setup()
{
    uint16_t overhead, start, end;

    Serial.begin(9600);
    TCCR1A = 0;
    TCCR1B = 1;

    // Time digitalWrite().
    overhead = 7;
    cli();
    start = TCNT1;
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    end = TCNT1;
    sei();
    Serial.print("digitalWrite(): ");
    Serial.print(end - start - overhead);
    Serial.println(" cycles");

    // Time direct port access.
    overhead = 4;
    cli();
    start = TCNT1;
    PORTD &= ~_BV(PD2);
    end = TCNT1;
    sei();
    Serial.print("direct port access: ");
    Serial.print(end - start - overhead);
    Serial.println(" cycles");
}

void loop(){}
```

The result was:

```
digitalWrite(): 78 cycles
direct port access: 2 cycles
```

I used an old Arduino core (1.0.5), but that function has not changed
since. You can try with your current core and see.

**PS**: In this program, the correct value for `overhead` can only be
determined by examining the generated assembly. It's a count of the
cycles you are measuring but do not directly belong to the operation you
really want to measure.

Comment: WOW! That's a difference! Very interesting to know. Where does all that extra MPU cycle usage come from?

Comment: @EnricBlanco: Here is the [link to the source code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/wiring_digital.c#L138) again. Look at the disassembly: saving registers to the stack and restoring them back (20 cycles) table lookups, tests... and 8 cycles of call overhead.

Comment: is there any related trick like this for the ESP8266?

Comment: @dandavis: I have no experience on that chip.